# What does 'out of' mean in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> In the past cheap oil has buoyed the world economy because **consumers
>   spend much more out of one extra dollar in their pocket than producers
>   do**.
>   <sub>Source: [Who’s afraid of cheap oil? | The Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21688854-low-energy-prices-ought-be-shot-arm-economy-think-again-whos-afraid-cheap)</sub>

I cann't figure out what doest it mean 'spend  much more of one extra dollar...than producers do'. Much more than one dollar? but why produces do? Does producers also spend much more dollars?

Comment: _Out of_ in your sentence refers to the source and means _from_. The sentence says in the past consumers paid the most of the cost of extracting oil so it was a profitable thing for producers. I think it means _from the whole amount of_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clause that confuses you is:

> consumers spend much more out of one extra dollar in their pocket than producers do
>   <sub>(Personally, I'd use *spent*, because it's *"in the past"*, and probably *pockets*, but, anyway.)</sub>

Note that it's not just "spend much more of one extra dollar". It's "spend much more **out of** one extra dollar **in their pocket**".

---

Let's look at the structure more closely:

> [ consumers
>   ​　　 　[ spend
>   ​　　　　　　　**much more**
>   ​　　　　　　　　　　[ out of one extra dollar in their pocket ]
>   ​　　 　]
>   ]
>   **​than**
>   ​[ producers
>   ​ ​　　 　[ do ]
>   ​]

The *do* in *producers do* is for: *spend (out of one extra dollar in their pocket)*.

---

So, the clause means that:

1. Given that there is one extra dollar in an average consumer's pocket.
2. Given that there is one extra dollar in an average producer's pocket.
3. The consumer would spend **much more** out of that one extra dollar **than** the producer would.

In other words, having an extra dollar in their pockets,
they both would spend some of it, but the consumer would spend more.

Comment: Note that I didn't really address the meaning of *out of* because the body of your question suggests that it wasn't *out of* that confused you. (It was the structure of the sentence, i.e., *much more ... than ... do*.) Just in case, *[out of](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of)* is frequently used this way, e.g., 7 out of 10; 42 out of 100 workers; 50 cents out of a dollar, etc.

Comment: Amazing explanations. Frankly, I've never get one like this. Yeah, it is mainly the structure that confused me.  Also thank you for the 'out of' explanation, I was not very understand it before.

Comment: Actually I am OK with *spend* as written. The bolded phrase seems to be stating a general rule of what happens. Without more context, I read it as occurring over time, from the past into the present. "In the past" just adds a perspective related to some other topic discussed. On *pockets* I agree, but primarily because most Western clothing has more than one pocket, but that is not necessarily true everywhere. Or it could be referring to a *symbolic pocket*.